# asp.net mvc many-to-many relationships in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net mvc project where have the search filter form. Also have 2 tables many-to-many relationships for example Students & Universities. And in my form display dropdown of universities. Then from form to action view fly university's id, where I need to sort whole my students table, to get students only by this university. Also I have another dropdowns for filtering, but their id's exist in the Student table instead of UniversityId which didn't include in Students table. And I dont know how and what I should to do. At this moment my query looks like next:

```
var model = repository.GetStudents()
.Where(x => x.DropId == (DropId?? x.DropId) && 
x.DropId1 == (DropId1 ?? x.DropId1) && 
//somewhere here must be expression for UniversityId
).ToList();
```

Somebody have any ideas?

**Edit:**

```
public class Student {
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public int DropId { get; set; }
public Drop Drop { get; set; }
public int DropId1 { get; set; }
public Drop1 Drop1 { get; set; }
public ICollection<University> Universities { get; set; }
}

public class University {
public int UniversityId { get; set; }
public string UniversityNameShort { get; set; }
public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post every Model including in this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've got the selected university's Id value, let's say in a variable called `universityId`, you can get the students of the university by this query:

```
repository.GetStudents()
          .Where(x => x.DropId == (DropId?? x.DropId) 
                   && x.DropId1 == (DropId1 ?? x.DropId1)
                   && x.Universities.Any(u => u.UniversityId == universityId)
).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks very good! @BortHunter you can also vote for this nice answer!